# sbt and scct .... module not found: reaktor#sbt-scct;0.2-SNAPSHOT

Tags: scala, sbt, code-coverage, scct

scala is version 2.10.2 and sbt is 0.13.0

I am trying to setup scct for scala unit test code coverage so in build.sbt
I added

```
seq(ScctPlugin.instrumentSettings : _*)
```

and in project/plugins.sbt I added

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

resolvers += "scct-github-repository" at "http://mtkopone.github.com/scct/maven-repo"

addSbtPlugin("reaktor" %% "sbt-scct" % "0.2-SNAPSHOT")
```

I get errors like ....

```
module not found: reaktor#sbt-scct;0.2-SNAPSHOT
```

Last message is

```
[warn] ==== scct-github-repository: tried
[warn]   http://mtkopone.github.com/scct/maven-repo/reaktor/sbt-scct_2.10_0.13/0.2-SNAPSHOT/sbt-scct-0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: reaktor#sbt-scct;0.2-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      reaktor:sbt-scct:0.2-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
```

I look in http://mtkopone.github.io/scct/maven-repo/reaktor/
and I see the one I seem to need is missing e.g. I see

```
sbt-scct_2.9.2_0.13/
scct_2.10/
and a bunch of others but no ... sbt-scct_2.10_0.13
```

Can you help ? (I am a sbt newbie)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SCCT has a new source code repository: https://github.com/SCCT/scct

As a result you can fetch a release version from maven central with `addSbtPlugin("com.github.scct" %% "sbt-scct" % "0.2")` in your plugins.sbt file.

My project to reproduce is on [GitHub](https://github.com/schleichardt/stackoverflow-answers/tree/so19400819).

**Update:**

The repository has been relocated at https://github.com/sqality/scct 
and you need `addSbtPlugin("com.sqality.scct" % "sbt-scct" % "version")` in your plugins.sbt file.

Comment: Many thanks ... that worked. It would be helpful I think if http://mtkopone.github.io/scct/ had links to this info.

Answer (score 1):

The original SCCT is inactive now.

Here are the two most active forks.

- http://github.com/sqality
- http://github.com/scoverage

Comment: Thanks, any recommendations regarding the relative merits of sqality vs. scoverage ?

Comment: I wrote scoverage so I'm biased :)

Comment: Scoverage is a complete re-write that supports statement level coverage and branch coverage. Sqality takes the excellent SCCT foundation and fixes a ton of bugs and really polishes it.